# Proof by induction with multiple lists

Tags: scala, functional-programming, induction, proof-of-correctness, equational-reasoning

I am following the Functional Programming in Scala lecture on Coursera and at the end of the video 5.7, Martin Odersky asks to prove by induction the correctness of the following equation :

```
(xs ++ ys) map f = (xs map f) ++ (ys map f)
```

How to handle proof by induction when there are multiple lists involved ?

I have checked the base cases of xs being Nil and ys being Nil.
I have proven by induction that the equation holds when xs is replaced by x::xs, but do we also need to check the equation with ys replaced by y::ys ?

And in that case (without spoiling the exercise too much...which is not graded anyway) how do you handle : `(xs ++ (y::ys)) map f` ?

This is the approach I have used on a similar example, to prove that

```
(xs ++ ys).reverse = ys.reverse ++ xs.reverse
```

Proof (omitting the base case, and easy x::xs case) :

```
(xs ++ (y::ys)).reverse
= (xs ++ (List(y) ++ ys)).reverse         //y::ys = List(y) ++ ys
= ((xs ++ List(y)) ++ ys).reverse         //concat associativity
= ys.reverse ++ (xs ++ List(y)).reverse   //by induction hypothesis (proven with x::xs)
= ys.reverse ++ List(y).reverse ++ xs.reverse //by induction hypothesis
= ys.reverse ++ (y::Nil).reverse ++ xs.reverse //List(y) = y :: Nil
= ys.reverse ++ Nil.reverse ++ List(y) ++ xs.reverse //reverse definition
= (ys.reverse ++ List(y)) ++ xs.reverse //reverse on Nil (base case)
= (y :: ys).reverse ++ xs.reverse         //reverse definition
```

Is this right ?

Comment: Look at the definitions of `++` and `map`. There are 2 lists, but which one do they decompose? ;)

Comment: Sure, but the definition doesn't make a proof...are we allowed to say "it has been proven correct by induction on one of the two lists of the expression, therefore the whole expression is correct"...I tend to think we can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property involves multiple lists, but `++` only recurses on its left argument. That's a hint that you can prove by induction on that left argument. In general, when proving a proposition about some recursive function, *the first thing you try is inducting on the same argument that function recurses on*.

I'll do this one for you as an example:

**Claim**: `(xs ++ ys) map f` = `(xs map f) ++ (ys map f)`

**Proof**: by induction on `xs`.

- Base case: `xs` = `Nil`

  - ***lhs*** = `(Nil ++ ys) map f` = `ys map f`

    (by `++`'s definition)
  - ***rhs*** = `(Nil map f) ++ (ys map f)` = `Nil ++ ys map f` = `ys map f`

    (by `map`'s, then `++`'s definitions)
  - Hence ***lhs*** = ***rhs***
- Inductive case: `xs` = `z :: zs`

  - ***hypothesis***: `(zs ++ ys) map f` = `(zs map f) ++ (ys map f)`
  - ***goal***: `((z :: zs) ++ ys) map f` = `((z :: zs) map f) ++ (ys map f)`
  - ***lhs*** = `(z :: (zs ++ ys)) map f` = `f(z) :: ((zs ++ ys) map f)` ***(1)***

    (by `map`'s definition)
  - ***rhs*** = `((z :: zs) map f) ++ (ys map f)` = `(f(z) :: (zs map f)) ++ (ys map f)`

    (by `map`'s definition)
  - in turn, ***rhs*** = `f(z) :: ((zs map f) ++ (ys map f))` ***(2)***

    (by `++`'s definition)
  - From ***hypothesis***, ***(1)*** and ***(2)***, we have proven ***goal***.

Therefore, we have proven the claim to be true reguardless of `xs`, `ys`, and `f`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment of @Phil says, first is a good understaning of what the methods `++` and `::` are doing on the lists the better way is the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

How can we prove properties of list programs?
The answer is by Structural induction!
Proof rule for proving a list property P(xs) via structural induction:

P(Nil) (base case)
 for all x,xs : P(xs) => P(x::xs) (induction step)

for all xs : P(xs) (consequence)

P(xs) in induction step is called induction hypothesis

for as the only important thing is xs, ys is fix proper List with lenght l, after proving for xs you can proof for ys, or see that is commutative

So let's apply induction and the definitions of the functions

P(xs): (xs ++ ys) map f = (xs map f) ++ (ys map f)

Base case we substitue xs by nil

```
(nil ++ ys) map f [definition of ++ ] 
ys map f  on the other hand 
(xs map f) ++ (ys map p) [apply map over NIL] 
(NIL) ++ (ys map p) [definition pf ++] 
ys map p
```

Induction Step

```
((x::xs) ++ ys) map f [definition ++]
(x:: (xs ++ ys)) map f [definition map]
f(x) :: ((xs ++ ys) map f) [induction hypothesis]
f(x) :: ((xs map f) ++ (ys map f)) [definition ++]
(f(x) :: (xs map f)) ++ (ys map f) [definition map]
(x::xs) map f ++ ys map f
```

q.e.d

for example another case in a scala work sheet

```
import scala.util.Random

// P : length ( append(as,bs) )) = length ( as ) + length (bs)

def length[T](as: List[T]): Int = as match {
    case Nil => 0
    case _::xs => 1 + length(xs)
}

def append[T](as: List[T], bs: List[T]): List[T] = as match {
  case Nil => bs
  case x :: xs => x :: append(xs, bs)
}

// base case  we substitute Nil for as in P

val a:List[Int] = Nil
val n = 10
val b:List[Int] = Seq.fill(n)(Random.nextInt).toList

length((append(a,b)))

length(a)

length(b)
```

import scala.util.Random

```
length: length[T](val as: List[T]) => Int




append: append[T](val as: List[T],val bs: List[T]) => List[T]






a: List[Int] = List()
n: Int = 10
b: List[Int] = List(1168053950, 922397949, -1884264936, 869558369, -165728826, -1052466354, -1696038881, 246666877, 1673332480, -975585734)

res0: Int = 10

res1: Int = 0

res2: Int = 10
```

[here](http://www.ist.tugraz.at/_attach/Publish/Swp14/swp-induction.pdf) you can find more examples

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is probably not very clear, your answer corresponds to the part that I had proven. The question I have is how do you go from "induction on one list" to "the whole expression is proven to be correct".

Comment: @Gael you only *need* to induct on one list and refer to the other list opaquely.